# Upload video, split it by size (on mb) and play it

Tags: video, split, upload, ffmpeg, stream

I'm trying to learn some using of code, and i'm want to know if it possible upload video, after upload split it by Mb.

For example :
**i have video . mp4 2.3 Mb that i uploaded. i want it split to**:

```
video 1 . mp4 (1 MB)
video 2 . mp4 (1 MB)
video 3 . mp4 (0.3 MB)
```

And after it i want open for example URL:

```
example.com/video/video.mp4
```

and it will know that the video is from 4 sources.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/) allows to split by size, e.g.

```
mp4box -splits 100000 filename.mp4
```

where 100000 refers to kilobyte count. Depending on keyframe placement, the resulting segment sizes may differ.